# Integral of digamma function

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration, special-functions

I was attempting to evaluate a series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Since $$\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{n(n+t)}dt,$$

I rewrote it as $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{1}{n(n+t)} \; dt$$

and switched the sum and integral:

$$\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+t)}dt$$

The sum is related to digamma. Specifically,

$$\frac{\gamma-\psi(t+1)}{t}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+t)}$$

Now, integrating this is the problem:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\gamma+\psi(t+1)}{t} \; dt=1.257746887\ldots$$

That $t$ in the denominator causes a fit.  I tried integration by parts, to no avail.

I ran it through Maple and it gave me $$1.257746887\ldots$$ which is indeed what the sum converges to.

Does anyone know if we can evaluate the above digamma integral? Perhaps a numerical approximation is the best we can do? After all, Maple would not give me a closed form; just the decimal solution. 
Can it be related to zeta or some other advanced function somehow?

Thanks very much for any input.

Comment: Not sure about a closed form, but there is yet another pretty expression for your sum: $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}\zeta(k+1)}{k}$$

Comment: BTW: [ISC](http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=1.257746886944369&lookup_type=simple) doesn't seem to have any ideas for a closed form.

Comment: Relatedly: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22088/infinite-product-experimental-mathematics-question (the constant you have above is the logarithm of the number I asked about in that MO question)

Comment: Two more "pretty" representations: $$\int_0^1 \frac{u\log\,u}{(1-u)\log(1-u)}\mathrm du=\int_0^1 \frac{(1-u)\log(1-u)}{u\log\,u}\mathrm du$$

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. Much appreciated. I thought that may be the case, but certainly wasn't sure. I suppose that's why Maple would only give a numerical solution.
I am glad I stumbled upon something interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This formula appeared in earlier work of Coffey ['Series of zeta values, the Stieltjes constants, and a sum S_γ(n)'](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0345v1) (see (38a) and following expressions),
in his paper of 2011 ['Series representations of the Riemann and Hurwitz zeta functions and series and integral representations of the first Stieltjes constant'](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5146v1) (1.23 and next)

as well as in Steven Finch's ['Continued Fraction Transformation III'](http://algo.inria.fr/csolve/kz3.pdf) (page 5)
see too his article concerning the related ['Khintchine-Levy constants'](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Pl5I2ZSI6uAC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62) (page 62 the expression for $\ln(W)$ at the middle right)

It seems that it may be written in many ways! For example :

$$S=-\sum_{k=2}^\infty \zeta'(k)$$

Comment: Finch's CFT III alternative [link](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~sfinch/csolve/kz3.pdf).