# Evaluation of $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n}\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: integration, euler-mascheroni-constant, digamma-function

Coming across the calculation of a special integral I get stuck on the following series, which I have given its integral representation :

$$\text{J}=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n}\ln\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x}\bigg(\psi(1+x)+\gamma \bigg)dx\,$$
Where $\psi$ denotes the digamma function and $\gamma$ represents the Euler-Mascheroni constant. I am wondering if such a series has a closed-form.

Comment: Related [Integral of digamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125641/integral-of-digamma-function) and [Infinite product experimental mathematics question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22088/infinite-product-experimental-mathematics-question)

Comment: @Sil Manythanks, from the links above it seems that this integral has no closed-form.

Comment: Possibly the sign infront of $\gamma$ should be $+$ ?

Comment: @Diger, just a typo, it is edited, thanks

Comment: The integral representation $$ J = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-u)\log(1-u)}{u\log(u)}\,du$$ follows from Frullani's theorem and allows a simple numerical evaluation.

Comment: Mathematica gives the numerical value $J=1.257746886944369630009899830495881528511540890\dots$. This gives nothing when put into the ISC.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my comment, since I found a better approximation. By the use of Binet's formula (see [Binet](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9)), one can derive $${\rm J}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k-1} \, \zeta(k)$$ which converges somewhat slowly. By partial summation this can be brought to $$\zeta(2) \log 2 + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2} \left[\Psi\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right) - \Psi\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)\right] \left[\zeta(k)-\zeta(k+1)\right] \, .$$ Another partial summation yields $$\zeta(2)\log 2 + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big\{ \Psi(n+1) \left[\zeta(2n+2)-\zeta(2n+1)\right] \\
- \Psi(n+1/2) \left[\zeta(2n+2)-\zeta(2n)\right] + \Psi(n) \left[\zeta(2n+1)-\zeta(2n)\right] \Big\}$$ which converges a lot faster with exponential order ${\cal O}\left(\frac{1}{n4^{n+2}}\right)$. Cutting the series after only 5 terms yields \begin{align}{\rm J}&\approx 1.257743 \tag{approximation} \\ {\rm J} &= 1.257746... \tag{exact}\end{align} correct up to 6 digits.

Interestingly the number is somewhat similar to the alike looking sum
$$\gamma=\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k} \, \zeta(k)$$
from which an alternative expression arises $${\rm J} = \gamma + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k \, \zeta(k)}{k(k-1)} \, .$$