# Is there a limit/convergence in that sequence of ratios of primeproducts?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

In another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4666292/1714) I discuss the function on primes
$$ r(p) = { p \over 2^{E_2} 3^{E_3} 5^{E_5} ... q^{E_q} } \tag 1
$$
where $p \in  \mathbb P$ and $q$ is the next smaller prime before $p$.
Here $$E_q = { q \over (q-1)^2 } \tag 2 $$
Looking at $p \lt 1e8$ it seems, this could converge to some value above $0.5221...$ but it might as well increase unboundedly with increasing $p$.

> Q: Does a limit  $ \lim_{p \to \infty} r(p)$ exist? And in case it exists, what value does it assume?

---

(Graphic from linked question):
[image]
Another graphic with x-scale doubly logarithmic:
[image: image2]
A graphic showing even more values (up to $p \lt 10^8$) but the upper and lower hullcurves giving some suggestion for convergence:
[image: image3]

Comment: I think one can formally find this limit by using the analogue ideas from mertens theorems. 
SEE : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666737/asymptotics-for-gn-sum-k-1n-1-frac-log-1-p-kp-k

Comment: If it has a closed form, dunno, need to think and work.

Comment: @Mick - hmm, Mertens-function is an interesting hint. (see one discussion of mine at MO https://mathoverflow.net/q/47469/7710) For that function one could derive that a limit exists (by R. Chapman's answer). But the appearance has more alternating values, while here it might be that we have some undoundedness, perhaps suggested by the double-logarithmic picture.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms yeah my comment was not very accurate. Here is an accurate estimate 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106260/interpolating-the-primorial-p-n

Comment: @GottfriedHelms see also this estimate (answer ) : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450525/is-there-a-better-upper-bound-for-the-primorial-x-than-4x?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: and maybe this relates : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firoozbakht%27s_conjecture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your suspicion is right; the limit exists and it converges to $0.5221$.

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime. We have $E_{p_n} = \frac{p_n}{(p_n-1)^2} = \frac{1}{p_n} + \frac{2}{p_n^2} + \frac{3}{p_n^3} + \cdots = \frac{1}{p_n} + f_{p_n}$

where $f_{p_n} = \frac{2}{p_n^2} + \frac{3}{p_n^3} + \cdots$. We have

$$
2^{E_2} 3^{E_3} ... q^{E_{p_n}} = (2^{\frac{1}{2}} 3^{\frac{1}{3}} ... p_n^{\frac{1}{p_{n}}}) . (2^{f_2} 3^{f_3} ... p_n^{f_{p_n}}) \tag 1
$$

Let us look at the two parts $2^{\frac{1}{2}} 3^{\frac{1}{3}} ... p_n^{\frac{1}{p_n}}$ and $2^{f_2} 3^{f_3} ... p_n^{f_{p_n}}$ separately.

For the first part, Mertens first theorem states that $ \sum_{ p \le p_n } \frac{\log p}{p} = \log p_n + B_3 + o(1)$ where [$B_3 \approx 1.332582$ is the Merten's constant](https://oeis.org/wiki/Talk:Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant). Hence

$$
2^{1/2} 3^{1/3} ... p_n^{1/p_n} \approx p_n e^{-B_3} \tag 2
$$

For the second part, we have

$$
2^{f_2} 3^{f_3} 5^{f_5}... p_n^{f_{p_n}} = \prod_{i = 1}^n p_i^{\sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{k}{p_i^k}} = \prod_{i = 1}^n p_i^{\frac{2p_i - 1}{p_i(p_i-1)^2}} \tag 3
$$

For the closed form of the sum on the above exponent, [refer to this link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=summation&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Sum%22%2C%20%22sumlowerlimit%22%7D%20-%3E%222%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22summation%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Sum%22%2C%20%22sumfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22x%2Fp%5Ex%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Sum%22%2C%20%22sumupperlimit2%22%7D%20-%3E%22infinity%22). Hence,

$$ 
\lim_{p \to \infty}r(p) = \lim_{n \to \infty}{ p_{n+1} \over 2^{1/2} 3^{1/3} ... p_n^{1/p_n}} \cdot { 1 \over 2^{f_2} 3^{f_3} ... p_n^{f_{p_n}}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e^{B_3} p_{n+1}}{p_n} \cdot \prod_{i = 1}^n p_i^{-\frac{2p_i - 1}{p_i(p_i-1)^2}} \tag 4
$$

Since $\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, $(4)$ reduces to

> $$  \lim_{p \to \infty}r(p) = e^{B_3} \prod_{p} p^{-\frac{2p - 1}{p(p-1)^2}} \approx 0.522174 $$

Comment: Well, this looks already very nice, thank you much! You showed some ideas which I wish I had found myself :-) I'll go through this later today. Thanks again!

Comment: Wow, the introduction of the Merten's constant in $B_3$ is a hit. Congrats! I'll mark your answer as "accepted". And again thanks for the lucide explanation!